# Is there a way to implement <T>(x: Promise<AsyncIterableIterator<T>>): AsyncIterableIterator<T> in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, promise, iterator, async-await, async-iterator

So I get `Promise<AsyncIterableIterator<T>>` and I need plain `AsyncIterableIterator<T>` how can I unwrap the `AsyncIterableIterator<T>` from under the promise?

Comment: Sure, why not? Have you tried it?

Comment: I'd guess `for await (const e of (await x)) yield e` should do.

Comment: i tried to implement interfaces bare-hands, but your async `for` is the spot on

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's actually quite simple. We want to implement the `AsyncIterableIterator` interface ourselves, and for every call to `next` we first unwrap the `Promise`.

```
function unwrapAsyncIterableIteratorPromise (input) {
  return {
    next (value) {
      return input.then((iterator) => iterator.next(value))
    },
    [Symbol.asyncIterator] () {
      return this
    }
  }
}
```

It's also on npm together with TypeScript typings:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/unwrap-async-iterable-iterator-promise